# Can Webservices be stateful? Can two different operations(from same client) of a stateful web-service be under same transaction?

Tags: web-services, rest, atomic, stateful, transactionmanager

I am a newbie in stateful webservices area. Please ignore if any of the below questions do not make sense.

1. I have mostly dealt with stateless webservices. One question in my mind is that can we pass session id to a web service thru the XML API. Is there already a provision for this(so that it becomes stateful)? Does a Java-XML api to invoke a web service has a provision to make use of cookies?
2. Are RESTful web services stateful? Is this the reason they are called RESTful?
3. Let's say I am using a stateful web-service. And I have two different operations where 'Atomicity' of operation has to maintained(take an example of Credit/Debit of card and cruz booking). Both have to be successful or neither.

Can such a thing be achieved using a web service?(because I dont know how transaction control can be applied to web services. It would have been easy if I had to deal with only services(ejb) layer).

If yes-this gives rise to another question-how transaction manager identify client context and does the same transaction context gets applied to these operations which should be part of one meaningful and atomic transaction?

Does this depend on the framework/programming language that we gonna use? For e.g. I want to achive this using JSF/SpringMVC UI and JAX-WS/Axis web service. If no, please let me know what other similar frameworks(from Java) have this and provides the solution. Servers - weblogic/jboss.

Thanks
Prakash

Comment: A web service is just some code set up to respond to incoming HTTP requests. It can do anything you code it to do. Your question is too broad to answer unless you narrow it to a specific problem, web service framework, programming language, etc.

Comment: Yes. I asked this question in a broader view. Cause I feel there would be similarities in architecture of various technologies(like Java, .Net). I really don't understand what you meant by your sentence -'It can do anything you code it to do'. This really does not provide the answer.
But if you want to know, what I am using-I have a UI created in JSF / Spring mvc that is calling JAX-WS / Axis web service. I don't know really if framework matters here. Servers I want to use are weblogic / jboss. Does the Web service framework(JAX-WS / Axis) have provision to executed under transaction context?

Comment: Does web-service end points come under transaction-manager's control? I am asking this because i have no idea whether the answer depends on support of JAX-WS / Axis or any other framework.

Comment: All those details need to be _in_ the question.

Comment: I think the question is clear from the title itself, although i had my queries which i described and asking. And having said that there are similarities in architecture from various technologies-it is wise to seek answer for the same. I am still waiting for someone who really knows the answer. If anyone who have worked on stateful webservices might have arrived to similar situation and knows how to solve the problem-please reply.

Comment: Or anyone who knows the answer partially(not complete) or thinks that this is specific to a framework/programming language that i am using-For them - 'I am using a UI created in Java(JSF/Spring MVC) that will invoke JAX-WS/Axis web service'. I took an example related to most popular frameworks from Java technology. So is there a way to achieve this(two different operations under same transaction context)? If yes, then can I say that web service end points also under control of transaction-manager(if I am using the mentioned frameworks)? - please reply.

Comment: I have edited the question and included the preferred technologies/frameworks for me. But someone still may come out with an answer in broader sense. Hence earlier tried to avoid the clutter.